# How to call data array to home.ctp cakephp3

Tags: php, html, cakephp

I am new to cakephp. I am trying to build home page with carousel.But I want to make the image in the slide get called from the slides table database.
Below is my carousel code in home.ctp

```
<div class="mbr-box mbr-section mbr-section--relative mbr-section--fixed-size mbr-section--bg-adapted item dark center mbr-section--full-height active" style="background-image: url(<?= ($slide->thumbnail) ?>);">
                <div class="mbr-box__magnet mbr-box__magnet--sm-padding">
                    <div class=" container">
                        <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                            <div class="mbr-hero">
                                <h1 class="mbr-hero__text">Slide 2</h1>
                                <p class="mbr-hero__subtext">Description</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mbr-buttons btn-inverse mbr-buttons--center"><a class="mbr-buttons__btn btn btn-lg btn-danger" href="#">HERE</a></div>
                        </div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

`style="background-image: url(<?= ($slide->thumbnail) ?>);"` is the code that i thought could call the image file from database(images/17860481920x1200-165.jpg). But all i got is a blank.

Can anyone help me. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Fetch the data at the controller and then set it for the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way:

```
cake bake cell Carousel
```

this create two files,

first CarouselCell.php in View/Cell

```
<?php
namespace App\View\Cell;

use Cake\View\Cell;

/**
 * Carousel cell
 */
class CarouselCell extends Cell
{

    /**
     * List of valid options that can be passed into this
     * cell's constructor.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_validCellOptions = [];

    /**
     * Default display method.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function display()
    {
    }
}
```

secound display.ctp in Template\Cell\Carousel folder.

In CarouselCell.php display method add:

```
public function display()
{
 $this->loadModel('Slides');
 $slides = $this->Slides->find('all');
 $this->set('slides', $slides->toArray());
}
```

in display.ctp

```
<?php foreach($slides as $slide) { ?>
YOUR CAROUSEL HTML HERE
<?php } ?>
```

On home.ctp

```
<?= $this->cell('Carousel');?>
```

Read more: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html

Comment: I still need help, When i add another slide, the image will be at the bottom. What should i do ? I add the coding above in the display.ctp.

Comment: I add all the three image active. I should add at the first image only. Thanks. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
// First you pass data from the controller:
public function home() {
       $slider = array('img1.jpg','img2.jpg');
        $this->set('slider', $slider);
    }

app/View/Pages/home.ctp

<?php print_r ($slider); ?>
```